# What is a multi-part binary input?

Tags: php, html, http

It is mentioned on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp). I know HTML, javsscript and some PHP and this is the first time I hear about it.

Comment: multi-part = multiple attachments. with POST data you have an ability to upload multiple files in one request.

Answer (score 3):

This allows the client (browser) to send multiple chunks of binary input (files) to the server via the `<input type="file" />` control. This data comes along with the rest of the POST values.

From the spec: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Answer (score 0):

The Jakarta Commons documentation explains it on a very clear way:

> The multipart post method is a different request body format for a
>   POST method. The media-type multipart/form-data follows the rules of
>   all multipart MIME data streams as outlined in RFC 1521. It is
>   intended for use in returning the data that comes about from filling
>   out a form, **particularly when the form requires binary data to be uploaded such as the contents of a file**.

Link:

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/methods/multipartpost.html